# smartctl harddisk check doesn't show Attribute

Tags: linux, ubuntu, monitoring, hard-drive, hardware

today i install on my linux server the app smartmontools, after testing my hardrive (raid1) he doesn't show the Attribute.
After the command

```
smartctl -a /dev/nvme0n1
```

,i get the result without Attribute about the hardisk :

```
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Number:                       SAMSUNG MZQLB960HAJR-00007
Serial Number:                      S437NE0M802932
Firmware Version:                   EDA5202Q
PCI Vendor/Subsystem ID:            0x144d
IEEE OUI Identifier:                0x002538
Total NVM Capacity:                 960,197,124,096 [960 GB]
Unallocated NVM Capacity:           0
Controller ID:                      4
Number of Namespaces:               1
Namespace 1 Size/Capacity:          960,197,124,096 [960 GB]
Namespace 1 Utilization:            194,981,310,464 [194 GB]
Namespace 1 Formatted LBA Size:     512
Local Time is:                      Thu Mar 26 15:08:55 2020 CET
Firmware Updates (0x17):            3 Slots, Slot 1 R/O, no Reset required
Optional Admin Commands (0x000f):   Security Format Frmw_DL NS_Mngmt
Optional NVM Commands (0x001f):     Comp Wr_Unc DS_Mngmt Wr_Zero Sav/Sel_Feat
Maximum Data Transfer Size:         512 Pages
Warning  Comp. Temp. Threshold:     87 Celsius
Critical Comp. Temp. Threshold:     88 Celsius
Namespace 1 Features (0x02):        NA_Fields

Supported Power States
St Op     Max   Active     Idle   RL RT WL WT  Ent_Lat  Ex_Lat
 0 +    10.60W       -        -    0  0  0  0        0       0

Supported LBA Sizes (NSID 0x1)
Id Fmt  Data  Metadt  Rel_Perf
 0 +     512       0         0
 1 -    4096       0         0

=== START OF SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

SMART/Health Information (NVMe Log 0x02, NSID 0x1)
Critical Warning:                   0x00
Temperature:                        43 Celsius
Available Spare:                    100%
Available Spare Threshold:          10%
Percentage Used:                    0%
Data Units Read:                    11,731,065 [6.00 TB]
Data Units Written:                 5,120,885 [2.62 TB]
Host Read Commands:                 2,507,634,522
Host Write Commands:                57,970,936
Controller Busy Time:               434
Power Cycles:                       47
Power On Hours:                     3,520
Unsafe Shutdowns:                   3
Media and Data Integrity Errors:    0
Error Information Log Entries:      1
Warning  Comp. Temperature Time:    0
Critical Comp. Temperature Time:    0
Temperature Sensor 1:               43 Celsius
Temperature Sensor 2:               47 Celsius
Temperature Sensor 3:               55 Celsius

Error Information (NVMe Log 0x01, max 64 entries)
No Errors Logged
```

what should i do, or is the manufacturer the reason ?

for any help, i'm grateful.

kind regards

blackbeard

Comment: All of the responses are determined by manufacturer, they don't even have to tell you what scales they're using for number ranges.

Comment: thanks.
this means that the manufacturer hasn'tt set up a control function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the responses are determined by manufacturer. They have to provide certain parameters to maintain SMART compliance, and they may provide additional features which, as they are understood, the SmartCtl tool developer will add to their application.

Manufacturers don't even have to tell what scales they're using for all of the number ranges which they provide. Some of that data in the tool has been acquired over time by watching how and why the numbers change.